# How to connect fan control switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, exhaust-fan

I bought a fan control switch to control my exhaust fan. In my socket, there's 3 live, 3 neutral and 3 ground wires.

However, the fan control switch circuit diagram only shows the location to connect the live positions. The common (2) seems to be for the neutral wires. So how do I connect it?

I have connected the live wires to 1 and 4.

[image]

I have attached the diagram

[image]
[image]
[image]

I need to update a bit. 1st of all, this socket previously houses a 2 gang switch, which has 2 holes each for live, neutral and ground. For the 3 wires of each type, 2 wires are in 1 hole, while the other single wire is in another hole.

Btw, I have just connect 2 live wires to "1", and 1 live wire to "4". 1 neutral wire to 2. The good news is it works. I can now control the fanspeed. But then I realise that another socket box above now can't work. Obviously, I broke some connections. I then try to connect 2 neutral wires to "2" and 1 neutral wire to "3" but it can't work. I also tried to connect all 3 neutral wires to "2" and I trip the whole circuit, causing a power shut down. Luckily, nothing was damaged.

So I can I solve this problem?

Comment: that diagram is very clear ... there are no external connections to 2 and 3

Comment: Are the three live wires connected together or separate?  If connected together,Turn off power first. then add one short piece of wire(black or wire colour) to the three live wires and to number 1 connection.

Comment: the 3 live wires are separated. As mentioned above, they are requiredfor the another socket above the current one.

Comment: A picture of the instructions without the arrows would be helpful - they're obscuring what could be important information on the drawing. Also, a picture of how it's currently wired and how it was wired before you started (you did take a "before" pic, right?) would be most helpful.

Comment: I have added the pics without the arrows. I did take a before pic, but it's a bit messy. anyway I have posted them. Also, as updated in the post, it works but the socket on top is not working. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Do the minimum you can do, then work up from there.

You say that there are *"3 live, 3 neutral and 3 ground"* wires in your switch box. Try to group those into 3 triples, (live, neutral, ground), that make up a single circuit.

(If this is a commercial building, or a house that was wired using individual wires rather than bundles like Romex, it may be difficult or impossible. In that case, try to recreate the groupings from the earlier switch configuration in the hopes that whoever did that knew more than you.)

Take one such bundle, and hook it up to your fan control. It seems like the connections are **L, N, and COMMON**? Perhaps the COMMON is an output? Your red arrows obstruct what might be an intersection.

At any rate, try hooking one live to L, neutral to N, and I don't know about the COMMON -- can you provide a picture without arrows?

Comment: "try hooking one up" seems like dangerous advice when working with electrical.